# How to print out the final selector in a jQuery method chain

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

If I have the following jQuery chain

```js
 let mpath = $('.wlc2022.confirm').find('.something');
```

how can I print out ".something" or "something" (in either jQuery or raw JavaScript syntax) to the console window because its the last selector that `mpath` is looking for?

I have tried...

```
console.log(mpath.val)
console.log(mpath.value)
```

But nothing so far...

Comment: You're asking to print out your own code. Why not just put your selector in a constant and print that?

Comment: A ***long*** time ago jQuery objects used to have a `selector` property which you could use for this. However it got removed because it wasn't accurate, and is generally a code smell of a problem which can normally be solved in a far better and more elegant way. Why exactly do you need to get the selector? It seems an odd request to retrieve something you already know at design-time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no API for that in modern (post-3.0) versions of jQuery. There used to be a `.selector` property on jQuery objects, but it was removed because it was unreliable.

Note also that `mpath` itself is not "looking for" anything; it gets the result of the jQuery-based expression. Probably the best way to do what you want would be to construct some sort of utility around that expression pattern, and have it retain that last selector and make it available somehow.